# Abnormally High Memory Utilization of Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

There is a 3 node Redis cluster setup running in a Kubernetes cluster. As of yesterday the Total memory usage was creeping up continuously (around 14.9GB at peak with 462274 keys).

Due to a Network instability the master node switched from redis-0 to redis-2 and Memory Utilization dropped to 5.4GB while the key count is 470994 (still the master node is redis-2)

What is the reason for a different memory utilization while number of keys greater than previous key count while a different node is the master?

#### redis.conf

maxmemory and eviction policy are not set

```
bind 0.0.0.0
protected-mode no
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 300
daemonize no
supervised no
pidfile "/var/run/redis_6379.pid"
loglevel notice
logfile ""
databases 5
always-show-logo yes
save 900 1
save 300 100
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename "dump.rdb"
rdb-del-sync-files no
dir "/data"
replica-serve-stale-data yes
replica-read-only yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-diskless-load disabled
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
replica-priority 100
acllog-max-len 128
lazyfree-lazy-eviction no
lazyfree-lazy-expire no
lazyfree-lazy-server-del no
replica-lazy-flush no
lazyfree-lazy-user-del no
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-use-rdb-preamble yes
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128
latency-monitor-threshold 0
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-listpack-entries 512
hash-max-listpack-value 64
list-max-listpack-size -2
list-compress-depth 0
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-listpack-entries 128
zset-max-listpack-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
stream-node-max-bytes 4kb
stream-node-max-entries 100
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit replica 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
dynamic-hz yes
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
rdb-save-incremental-fsync yes
jemalloc-bg-thread yes
```

#### redis-0 logs

```
1:M 07 Jun 2022 22:59:34.691 * Background saving terminated with success
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:06:50.290 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:06:50.684 * Background saving started by pid 21
21:C 07 Jun 2022 23:08:03.628 * DB saved on disk
21:C 07 Jun 2022 23:08:03.887 * Fork CoW for RDB: current 2 MB, peak 2 MB, average 2 MB
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:08:04.300 * Background saving terminated with success
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:11.139 # Connection with replica client id #95 lost.
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:21.439 # Connection with replica 10.233.93.179:6379 lost.
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.397 * Before turning into a replica, using my own master parameters to synthesize a cached master: I may be able to synchronize with the new master with just a partial transfer.
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.397 * Connecting to MASTER 10.233.77.57:6379
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.397 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.397 * REPLICAOF 10.233.77.57:6379 enabled (user request from 'id=382 addr=10.233.122.249:35692 laddr=10.233.122.248:6379 fd=8 name=sentinel-62b0b9cd-cmd age=10 idle=0 flags=x db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=4 qbuf=200 qbuf-free=20274 argv-mem=4 multi-mem=180 rbs=1024 rbp=1024 obl=45 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=22480 events=r cmd=exec user=default redir=-1 resp=2')
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.402 # CONFIG REWRITE executed with success.
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.405 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.407 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.408 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request 4e8714d0f9b9b6e03d6c6e77175d8e4e0bc4cc0e:51477133).
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.409 * Full resync from master: 50740cce7a6e8a8f6336237eee4a3bd9f749ee86:51440060
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:17:49.782 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 2095263762 bytes from master to disk
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:03.086 * Discarding previously cached master state.
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:03.086 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Flushing old data
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:10.830 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Loading DB in memory
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:10.862 * Loading RDB produced by version 7.0.0
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:10.862 * RDB age 49 seconds
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:10.863 * RDB memory usage when created 3148.61 Mb
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:28.698 * Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 462376, keys expired: 0.
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:28.700 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Finished with success
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:28.790 * Background append only file rewriting started by pid 23
23:C 07 Jun 2022 23:18:52.057 * SYNC append only file rewrite performed
23:C 07 Jun 2022 23:18:52.138 * Fork CoW for AOF rewrite: current 2 MB, peak 2 MB, average 2 MB
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:52.279 * Background AOF rewrite terminated with success
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:52.291 * Removing the history file appendonly.aof.16.incr.aof in the background
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:52.294 * Removing the history file appendonly.aof.16.base.rdb in the background
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:18:52.304 * Background AOF rewrite finished successfully
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:22:02.953 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:22:03.051 * Background saving started by pid 24
24:C 07 Jun 2022 23:22:26.493 * DB saved on disk
24:C 07 Jun 2022 23:22:26.574 * Fork CoW for RDB: current 1 MB, peak 1 MB, average 1 MB
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:22:26.732 * Background saving terminated with success
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:31:20.700 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
```

#### redis-2 logs

```
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:04:06.345 * Background saving started by pid 22
22:C 07 Jun 2022 23:05:18.079 * DB saved on disk
22:C 07 Jun 2022 23:05:18.351 * Fork CoW for RDB: current 1 MB, peak 1 MB, average 1 MB
1:S 07 Jun 2022 23:05:18.750 * Background saving terminated with success
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:08.397 # Connection with master lost.
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:08.397 * Caching the disconnected master state.
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:08.397 * Discarding previously cached master state.
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:08.397 # Setting secondary replication ID to 4e8714d0f9b9b6e03d6c6e77175d8e4e0bc4cc0e, valid up to offset: 51407274. New replication ID is 50740cce7a6e8a8f6336237eee4a3bd9f749ee86
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:08.397 * MASTER MODE enabled (user request from 'id=33 addr=10.233.83.162:54926 laddr=10.233.77.57:6379 fd=22 name=sentinel-5a1cf691-cmd age=4008 idle=0 flags=x db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=4 qbuf=188 qbuf-free=20286 argv-mem=4 multi-mem=169 rbs=2048 rbp=1024 obl=45 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=23493 events=r cmd=exec user=default redir=-1 resp=2')
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:08.403 # CONFIG REWRITE executed with success.
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:21.526 * Replica 10.233.93.179:6379 asks for synchronization
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:21.527 * Partial resynchronization not accepted: Requested offset for second ID was 51475879, but I can reply up to 51407274
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:21.527 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:21.694 * Background saving started by pid 23
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.408 * Replica 10.233.122.248:6379 asks for synchronization
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.408 * Partial resynchronization not accepted: Requested offset for second ID was 51477133, but I can reply up to 51407274
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:28.409 * Waiting for end of BGSAVE for SYNC
23:C 07 Jun 2022 23:17:49.291 * DB saved on disk
23:C 07 Jun 2022 23:17:49.394 * Fork CoW for RDB: current 99 MB, peak 212 MB, average 136 MB
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:17:49.536 * Background saving terminated with success
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:18:03.074 * Synchronization with replica 10.233.93.179:6379 succeeded
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:18:03.087 * Synchronization with replica 10.233.122.248:6379 succeeded
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:31:13.208 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:31:13.313 * Background saving started by pid 24
24:C 07 Jun 2022 23:31:40.058 * DB saved on disk
24:C 07 Jun 2022 23:31:40.173 * Fork CoW for RDB: current 2 MB, peak 2 MB, average 1 MB
1:M 07 Jun 2022 23:31:40.383 * Background saving terminated with success
```

#### latest redis-cli info

```
# Server
redis_version:7.0.0
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:e7d3349b21c83e26
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
monotonic_clock:POSIX clock_gettime
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:c11-builtin
gcc_version:10.3.1
process_id:1
process_supervised:no
run_id:dd0da5308fcb09bebabeca08f93c8172aa10bafb
tcp_port:6379
server_time_usec:1654704006009467
uptime_in_seconds:89655
uptime_in_days:1
hz:10
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:10536837
executable:/data/redis-server
config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf
io_threads_active:0

# Clients
connected_clients:79
cluster_connections:0
maxclients:10000
client_recent_max_input_buffer:20480
client_recent_max_output_buffer:20504
blocked_clients:0
tracking_clients:0
clients_in_timeout_table:0

# Memory
used_memory:5472656120
used_memory_human:5.10G
used_memory_rss:5627080704
used_memory_rss_human:5.24G
used_memory_peak:15911668368
used_memory_peak_human:14.82G
used_memory_peak_perc:34.39%
used_memory_overhead:25379484
used_memory_startup:858264
used_memory_dataset:5447276636
used_memory_dataset_perc:99.55%
allocator_allocated:5473133208
allocator_active:5474054144
allocator_resident:5629345792
total_system_memory:68112744448
total_system_memory_human:63.43G
used_memory_lua:31744
used_memory_vm_eval:31744
used_memory_lua_human:31.00K
used_memory_scripts_eval:0
number_of_cached_scripts:0
number_of_functions:0
number_of_libraries:0
used_memory_vm_functions:32768
used_memory_vm_total:64512
used_memory_vm_total_human:63.00K
used_memory_functions:184
used_memory_scripts:184
used_memory_scripts_human:184B
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
allocator_frag_ratio:1.00
allocator_frag_bytes:920936
allocator_rss_ratio:1.03
allocator_rss_bytes:155291648
rss_overhead_ratio:1.00
rss_overhead_bytes:-2265088
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.03
mem_fragmentation_bytes:154464496
mem_not_counted_for_evict:34088
mem_replication_backlog:1048580
mem_total_replication_buffers:1086712
mem_clients_slaves:38136
mem_clients_normal:399784
mem_cluster_links:0
mem_aof_buffer:112
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.2.1
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
lazyfreed_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
async_loading:0
current_cow_peak:0
current_cow_size:0
current_cow_size_age:0
current_fork_perc:0.00
current_save_keys_processed:0
current_save_keys_total:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:731
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1654703970
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:32
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_saves:259
rdb_last_cow_size:5439488
rdb_last_load_keys_expired:0
rdb_last_load_keys_loaded:462299
aof_enabled:1
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:71
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_rewrites:1
aof_rewrites_consecutive_failures:0
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:10428416
module_fork_in_progress:0
module_fork_last_cow_size:0
aof_current_size:8870237917
aof_base_size:6729679707
aof_pending_rewrite:0
aof_buffer_length:0
aof_pending_bio_fsync:0
aof_delayed_fsync:0

# Stats
total_connections_received:6084
total_commands_processed:5994894
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:36
total_net_input_bytes:9159174280
total_net_output_bytes:10728134634
instantaneous_input_kbps:14.51
instantaneous_output_kbps:47.50
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:2
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:2
expired_keys:15
expired_stale_perc:0.00
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
expire_cycle_cpu_milliseconds:12542
evicted_keys:0
evicted_clients:0
total_eviction_exceeded_time:0
current_eviction_exceeded_time:0
keyspace_hits:3786429
keyspace_misses:36072
pubsub_channels:3
pubsub_patterns:1
latest_fork_usec:142931
total_forks:260
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0
total_active_defrag_time:0
current_active_defrag_time:0
tracking_total_keys:0
tracking_total_items:0
tracking_total_prefixes:0
unexpected_error_replies:0
total_error_replies:3228
dump_payload_sanitizations:0
total_reads_processed:4293751
total_writes_processed:7534562
io_threaded_reads_processed:0
io_threaded_writes_processed:0
reply_buffer_shrinks:123558
reply_buffer_expands:163328

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:2
slave0:ip=10.233.93.179,port=6379,state=online,offset=2168514425,lag=1
slave1:ip=10.233.122.248,port=6379,state=online,offset=2168514425,lag=1
master_failover_state:no-failover
master_replid:50740cce7a6e8a8f6336237eee4a3bd9f749ee86
master_replid2:4e8714d0f9b9b6e03d6c6e77175d8e4e0bc4cc0e
master_repl_offset:2168514425
second_repl_offset:51407274
repl_backlog_active:1
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:2167448036
repl_backlog_histlen:1066390

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:597.455126
used_cpu_user:953.227128
used_cpu_sys_children:1520.911712
used_cpu_user_children:6254.560210
used_cpu_sys_main_thread:581.954406
used_cpu_user_main_thread:946.707373

# Modules

# Errorstats
errorstat_ERR:count=3012
errorstat_LOADING:count=216

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=471001,expires=2,avg_ttl=207531
```